# outputting content based on whether variable object equals "true"

Tags: javascript

I thought this would be straight forward after reading through w3c tutorials etc! But I appear to have something incorrect as the code doesn't output anything!

The variable is set based on whether the user is logged in or not:

```
var theJSON={"LOGGEDIN":false};

var theJSON={"LOGGEDIN":true};
```

I am then trying to show on the front end whether the user is logged in or not:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if (typeof(theJSON[LOGGEDIN]) == true ) {

document.write ("Logged in")

} else {

document.write ("Not logged in");
}
```

i must be missing/mistyping something so simple?

Comment: FYI, this question has nothing to do with JSON. JSON is a data-exchange format like XML, CSV or YAML. `var theJSON={"LOGGEDIN":true};` is a object literal though.

Answer (score 2):

There a couple of things wrong in your code:

When you try to access the `LOGGEDIN` property of the object, you are missing quotation marks. The expression `theJSON[LOGGEDIN]` will first try to get the value of the **variable** `LOGGEDIN` to use its value as property name. If such a variable does not exist (like it is in your example), the code will throw an error.

Now, The **value** of `theJSON['LOGGEDIN']` is `true` and the **type** of the value is a **boolean**. `typeof(theJSON['LOGGEDIN']) == true` will *never* be true, because the `typeof` operator returns a string with the name of the data type, i.e. `typeof(theJSON['LOGGEDIN]')` will return `"boolean"`.

If you just want to test whether the value is true, do:

```
if (theJSON['LOGGEDIN'])
```

---

w3schools is really not the best site to start learning about JavaScript, have a look at http://eloquentjavascript.net/ and the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) instead.

Comment: I updated the script to the suggested above, but is simply returning blank. There must be an issue elsewhere, the script is simply detecting whether the "LOGGEDIN" is set to true or false.

The logged in status is being set in a separate ajax script.

Comment: Well, the issue you could be with your other script or with the fact that you are using `document.write`. It's impossible to tell without more information. The logic itself works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ezA7q/.

Comment: Thanks for your help Felix, I can see the script works perfect on jsfiddle, I shall dig into the other script and see if the error lies there.

I basically have this linked in my header:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://urlhere/index.cfm?go=cAjax.getUserStatus"></script>

Which when I go to the url it is displaying the var theJSON={"LOGGEDIN":false}; no problem.

Strange!

Comment: FWIW, this is not Ajax. You are just including another JavaScipt script. It should still work though. "Debugging" whole applications or process does not work via Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

if (typeof(theJSON["LOGGEDIN]") == true )
or 
if (typeof(theJSON.LOGGEDIN) == true )

BTW, better use === instead of ==

if the value is number 1 it will still pass the condition.

Comment: why not just use `if (theJSON.LOGGEDIN)` ?

Comment: It depends, if the value should be a bool, if (theJSON.LOGGEDIN) is not suitable. @GerardWesterhof

Comment: This will always be `false`. `typeof` returns a string, not a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `theJSON` is an actual object as given, not a JSON string. If it was you'd need to parse it as suggested.

The expression `theJSON[LOGGEDIN]` is incorrect syntax, you can either say `theJSON.LOGGEDIN` or `theJSON["LOGGEDIN"]`. And as this is a boolean, `typeof(theJSON.LOGGEDIN) == "boolean"`.

The expression is a boolean, but it's *value* is `true`, so you can just write `if (theJSON.LOGGEDIN)`.